# add folder to classpath in RCP product

Tags: java, osgi, classpath, classloader, rcp

We have an RCP product based on features which comprise several plugins. Each plugin uses an `OSGi` bundle manifest.

One of this plugin contains a set of libraries (`Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives`) made by third party.

Now the problem. One of this libraries is looking for a configuration file in the following way:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

It is clear that the folder containing the file must be added to the classpath. So I added in the manifest of the plugin the following:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: resources/
```

and I placed the configuration file in there (of course there also other `Bundle-ClassPath:` for the jars and the `resources` is together with them).

If I test the product within eclispe the file is found and everything works but, as soon as I export the product, the file is not found anymore (even if the `resources` folder is included in the exported plugin).

I think that I lack some OSGI property in the run configuration but I have no idea about how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The folder "resources" must be set as output folder in build.properties of the plugin:
output.. = bin/,\
           resources/